# Unable to define siteprism element from a given label text

Tags: capybara, site-prism

I'm using a cucumber/ruby/capybara/siteprism framework and I'm having problems identifying elements as either we're missing the ids, names, etc or they create them with a  in real time.

I was mainly trying to define some of those elements in a siteprism page object model. For example, I was trying to enter some data in the 'input' field for 'First Name' below:

```html
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="input_field_dec_<random_number>">
First Name
<span class="required"></span>
</label>
<div class="controls">
<input id="input_field_dec_<random_number>" class=" span5" type="text" value="" scripttofire="SetUserFirstName('input_field_dec_<random_number>')" required="required" name="input_field_dec_<random_number>" data-val-required="First Name is required" data-val-regex-pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9_ \-\']*$" data-val-regex="Only alphabetic and numeric characters allowed" data-val="true">
<span class="field-validation-valid help-inline" data-valmsg-for="input_field_dec_<random_number>" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to pass the label text (eg: 'First Name' - ignoring the spaces around, something like - contains='First Name') and then find the input element inside to set it up?

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
element :first_name_field, :xpath, "//label[contains(text()='Continue'])/<and here something to find the input field?>" but cannot figure it out...
```

Comment: Try `element :first_name_field, :field, 'First Name'`

Comment: @Thomas, that specific example worked your way. However, it's not working in the next code, which seems similar to me?

    <div class="input-append">
  <label>Street or Postcode</label>
  <input type="text" data-bind="textInput:AddressDetail.PostCode, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" class="searchAddress input-block-level valid">                                       
</div>   ..... in this case, I was using element :search_box, :field, 'Street or Postcode' .... and I get: "Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find field "Street or Postcode""

Comment: It won't work in that case because there is nothing linking the label and the input since the label doesn't wrap the input or have a 'for' attribute

Comment: I see, I've got loads of situations like that (every control is done in a different way, I'm trying to think how to ask another question about radio buttons in siteprism. I've not seen any example to see how to define those ones :( ). Could you think of a different way to define this last element? maybe something like xpath/find-the-parent/navigate-to-the-child-input-field?

Comment: Radio button should work with `element :some_name, :radio_button, 'value or text'`. Your other example is doable with XPath using the following-sibling axis

Comment: Thanks, I cannot make the 'following-sibling' to work. Could you pls see if you can think of the syntax in that example to give it a go?

And for learning purposes, do you know if there's a place where they detail the available selectors, like :radio_button, :field, ... (maybe other selectors for links, check_boxes, etc). I didn't know where to find that info either. 

I'll mark the question as answered anyway, but I thought it might be better to ask those 2 doubts here? or is it better to create new questions for them? just to fully understand this area...

Comment: I added a full answer you can accept, with syntax I think should select the following sibling input (Note: I didn't actually try the code but it should be close) and a link to all the selectors provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capybara provides a bunch of built-in "selectors" that can be used for this, and you can add your own if you find it necessary.  You can see the provided selectors by either building the Capybara docs yourself (rubydocs doesn't run the custom yard code used to generate that part of the docs) or by browsing the file where they are implemented - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/selector.rb#L47

For your original example you can use the :field selector

```
element :first_name_field, :field, 'First Name'
```

which will match on the inputs associated label text.  For you second example (from the comments) where the input and label have no connection (wrapped or `for` attribute) you should be able to do something like

```
element :some_field, :xpath, ".//label[contains(normalize-space(string(.)), 'label text')]/following-sibling::*[1]/self::input"
```

If you wanted to make that reusable you could add your own "selector" like

```
Capybara.add_selector(:sibling_input) do
  label "Label adjacent sibling input"
  xpath do |locator|
    XPath.descendant(:label)[XPath.string.n.is(locator)].next_sibling(:input)
  end
end
```

which could then be used as

```
element :some_field, :sibling_input, 'label text'
```

Comment: wow, difficult the xpath expression for the following-sibling example. I'll give it a go, although I don't really understand it yet.

I wanted to say, thank you very much for the help, the explanations, the links, and the patience!!! Really appreciated man, thanks so much!

Comment: @mickael You're welcome, the XPath I provided could maybe be simplified a little since it was generated from the XPath DSL I used in the add_selector (xpath gem - https://github.com/jnicklas/xpath) rather than written by hand.  Basically it just says find a label that contains the specified text, and then find the adjacent sibling (XPath is 1 based on indexes - so [1] gets the first following sibling) as long as that sibling is an input element.